# SQL Order Chars Numerically - Node Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I have a column of numbers stored as chars separated by periods - which is used as a parent-child grouping mechanism. Having issues ordering due to the nature of the varchar and 100 coming before 11, as highlighted in bold below:

01
01.01
01.02
01.03
01.03.01
01.03.02
...
01.03.10
**01.03.100

01.03.101**

01.03.11
01.03.12
...
01.04
01.04.01
01.04.01.01
01.04.01.02
01.04.01.03
01.04.02
01.04.03
02
02.01

etc

Any thoughts on how can I order these chars numerically? There could potentially be unlimited child nodes, so this isn't impossible:

nn.nn.nn.nn.nn.nn.nn.nn.nn.nn etc

Thank you!

Comment: By unlimited, are you referring to how high the numbers can go, or how many periods there might be (or both)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a limit to the *depth*<sup>1</sup> of the tree, then you can write something like:

```
declare @t table (OrdCol varchar(50) not null)
insert into @t (OrdCol) values
('01'),
('01.01'),
('01.02'),
('01.03'),
('01.03.01'),
('01.03.02'),
('01.03.10'),
('01.03.100'),
('01.03.101'),
('01.03.11'),
('01.03.12'),
('01.04'),
('01.04.01'),
('01.04.01.01'),
('01.04.01.02'),
('01.04.01.03'),
('01.04.02'),
('01.04.03'),
('02'),
('02.01')

select OrdCol from
(select OrdCol,CAST('<a><b>' + REPLACE(OrdCol,'.','</b><b>') + '</b></a>' as xml) as xOrd from @t
) t
order by
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[1]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[2]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[3]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[4]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[5]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[6]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[7]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[8]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[9]','int'),
    xOrd.value('(a/b)[10]','int')
```

<sup>1</sup>Why I asked a clarifying comment to your question about which way "unlimited" children is meant to be interpreted. This query deals with an unlimited number of children at each level, but only deals with a depth of up to 10.

---

Unlimited depth version, works provided that there's at most one leading `0` on any of the numbers:

```
select OrdCol from
(select OrdCol,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('.' + OrdCol + '.','.0','.'),'.','/') as hierarchyid) as hOrd from @t
) t
order by
    hOrd
```

Which just munges the string until it fits a format castable to [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx), which already performs sorts in the order you expected. Of course, if this is valid, you might consider changing the column datatype to use this type anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Depth is potentially unlimited. Completely unmanageable in the category list, but potential. 10 should suffice, but if you have additional thoughts around unlimited depth, I am all ears. And thank you kindly.

Comment: @Mike250 - Updated with an unlimited depth version that works provided there's at most 1 leading `0` on any of the numbers, and your using SQL Server 2008 or later.

Comment: Yes, > SQL 2008. Yes, one leading 0 at most. Yes this is what I need. Thank you!